# Set<Object> to Map<String, Set<Long>> java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assume I have the next class structure:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Section {

    private Long id;
    
    private Set<Grid> grids;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Grid {

    private Long id;
    
    private Set<Row> rows;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Row {
    private Long id;
    
    private String email;
}
```

and I have this set of objects:

```
Set<Section> sections;
```

let's imagine this section set values as a JSON in the next structure :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "grids": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "rows" [
          {
            "id": 50,
            "email": "email1@test.com"
          },
          {
            "id": 51,
            "email": "email2@test.com"
          }
        ]
      }  
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "grids": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "rows" [
          {
            "id": 60,
            "email": "email1@test.com"
          }
        ]
      }  
    ]
  }  
]
```

Just imagine I have multiple sections and these sections have multiple grids and each grid has multiple rows and the email attribute in each row could exist in different grids.

Now I need to convert this **Set** to java.util.**Map<String, Set>** and this map represent Row object email as a key and group of Section ids as a value of that map key.
so I need the result like that **Map<email, Set<section1Id, section2id, etc...>>**
something like this in JSON (it's just for clarifying the idea):

```
[
  {
    "key": "email1@test.com",
    "value": [1, 2] // Section ids
  },
  {
    "key": "email2@test.com",
    "value": [1] // Section ids
  }
]

OR like that (whatever)

[
  "email1@test.com": {1, 2},
  "email2@test.com": {1}
]
```

How I can achieve this using Java 8 streaming?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
// ...snip...
sections.stream()
        .flatMap(section->section.getGrids()
                                 .stream()
                                 .map(Grid::getRows)
                                 .flatMap(Set::stream)
                                 .map(row->new Pair(row.getEmail(), section.getId())))
        .collect(groupingBy(Pair::getKey, mapping(Pair::getValue, toSet())));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 9 or newer, your can do it in a very concise way without the need of third party libraries:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.Map.entry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

Map<String, Set<Long>> result = sections.stream()
        .flatMap(section -> section.getGrids().stream()
                .flatMap(grid -> grid.getRows().stream())
                .map(row -> entry(row.getEmail(), section.getId())))
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toSet())));
```

Comment: The problem is for this project I am using java8, I know it's applicable to doing it in a simple way from java9 but as you see I wrote java8 in the question title. anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: In order to workaround the absence of the Java 9 Map.entry() method, you can use Apache Commons' Tuple or create your own helper class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about streaming. It can be achieved with a simple foreach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Section> sections = Set.of(....);
        Map<String, Set<Long>> result = new HashMap<>();
        sections.forEach(section -> 
                                 section.getGrids()
                                         .forEach(grid -> 
                                                          grid.getRows().forEach(row -> {
                                                            if (result.containsKey(row.getEmail()))
                                                                result.get(row.getEmail()).add(section.getId());
                                                                else result.put(row.getEmail(), Set.of(section.getId()));
                                                          })));
    }
```

Comment: I am already doing it with that simple for each :) but i need it using streaming, anyway thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two step operation to get the desired output format. Have a look at it, if fits your use case

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class P5 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Row r1 = new Row(50L, "email1@test.com");
    Row r2 = new Row(51L, "email2@test.com");
    Row r3 = new Row(60L, "email1@test.com");
    Row[] arr1 = {r1, r2};
    Row[] arr2 = {r3};

    Grid[] g1 = {new Grid(10L, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr1)))};
    Grid[] g2 = {new Grid(11L, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr2)))};

    Set<Section> sections = new HashSet<>();
    sections.add(new Section(1L, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(g1))));
    sections.add(new Section(2L, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(g2))));

    Map<Long, List<String>> minify = sections.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(section -> section.id,
            section -> section.grids.stream().flatMap(grid -> grid.rows.stream())
                .map(row -> row.email)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));

    Map<String, Set<Long>> result = minify.keySet().stream()
        .flatMap(key -> minify.get(key).stream().map(email -> new Pair<>(
            key, email))).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Pair::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Pair::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));

    System.out.println(result);
  }

  static class Section {
    private Long id;
    private Set<Grid> grids;
    public Section(Long id, Set<Grid> grids) {
      this.id = id;
      this.grids = grids;
    }
  }

  static class Grid {
    private Long id;
    private Set<Row> rows;
    public Grid(Long id, Set<Row> rows) {
      this.id = id;
      this.rows = rows;
    }
  }

  static class Row {
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    public Row(Long id, String email) {
      this.id = id;
      this.email = email;
    }
  }

}
```

RESULT

```
{email2@test.com=[1], email1@test.com=[1, 2]}
```